# how to update sqlite python table Based on match between another table

Tags: python, database, sqlite, join, sql-update

I tried to use the following code but it is giving errors:

```
import sqlite3    
conn = sqlite3.connect('stock.db')  
cursor = conn.cursor()
   

    conn.execute("UPDATE COMSEC_STOCK SET COMSEC_STOCK.quantity = COMSEC_STOCK.quantity -1 FROM COMSEC_STOCK, Comsec_Out_Temp WHERE COMSEC_STOCK.product_id = Comsec_Out_Temp.product_id")
        
    cursor.close()    
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite, the update column(s) on the left-hand side of the `SET` statement should not be qualified with the table's name/alias.

Also, you should not use the updated table in the `FROM` clause.

Write your code like this:

```
UPDATE COMSEC_STOCK 
SET quantity = COMSEC_STOCK.quantity -1 
FROM Comsec_Out_Temp 
WHERE Comsec_Out_Temp.product_id = COMSEC_STOCK.product_id;
```

or, better with aliases for the tables:

```
UPDATE COMSEC_STOCK AS s
SET quantity = s.quantity -1 
FROM Comsec_Out_Temp AS t 
WHERE t.product_id = s.product_id;
```

Comment: when i used this it only updated one time, how can i use it to update through the whole column to check if there is another match

Comment: @user21030066 I don't know what you mean. I only see the query that you posted in your question for which I mentioned the syntactical errors. Without the definitions of the tables with sample data and expected results I can't say.